# Two-state button: Show current state or next state?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

I have an action bar with a button to flip between two different views (list and tree). Should the button show (a) the current view or (b) the view that will be shown if the user clicks the button?

This is an age-old UI problem with no "right answer", only UI standards, so I'm trying to understand if there's any standard on this in Android.

Comment: This is asked here http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan It seems like an action bar is showing state, which makes me think the button appearance should match current state.

Answer (score 1):

I agree on the 'age-old' part. Myself I'm still questioning - when acting as a user, not a developer ;-) - what the button in front of me will do when I click it: turn on Shuffle or turn it of.
Now very pleased to come up with a feasible answer.
Since the user has a clear visual clue on the state the current presentation is in (List or Tree) the button would show the alternate option. Then the user knows that there is an alternate option and hopefully the button displays where it will take the user.

For more unclear situations I would still go with this approach. The user either knows or perhaps can deduce the current 'state' of the app ("hey it plays a whole different song now, so it is in shuffle"). So the button will bring me to another state, the one displayed.

Why display what the app is already doing and not displaying where a buttonpress will take the user?